# Is achieving session isolation with php-webdriver / ghostdriver / PhantomJS 1.9 possible?

Tags: php, webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm trying to achieve session isolation through facebooks php webdriver / ghost driver and phantomjs. I would like to run concurrent tests without the sessions/tests interfering with each other.

I've researched this as much as I can but I'm quite new to phantomjs so its left me rather confused. I can see [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/170) its included in ghostdriver 1.1.1 but that's not in phamtomjs 1.9, its in 2 which I don't believe works with facebooks php webdriver?

I can also see its discussed here for phantomjs [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11417) and [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11535).

Am I correct in thinking this can only be done in phantomjs 2? If it is possible in phantomjs 1.9 with ghostdriver and php-webdriver could someone show me exactly how?

Comment: How about using multiple PhantomJS instances (different host ports)?

Comment: I did consider that, but can I manage those different instances from with the PHP scripts? As in exec a new instance on a random port, run the tests then close the instance from within the PHP script.